# How to solve via on pad without plugging?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

There are some vias on pad in my design. I've read some articles and know that these vias should be plugged to avoid solder wicking. However, the board house told me that they can't provide a plugging service. Besides, it's impossible for me to move all the vias out of the pads because of the narrow space.

Can someone help me to find another solution to handle these vias on pad properly?
[image]

Comment: Those vias are gigantic. Is that the minimum size that your PCB house can do?

Comment: Easy solution: Take your design to a different PCB shop.

Comment: Blind vias would help, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Is this a land-grid array part, or just a bunch of 2-terminal parts packed together?  In the second case, there's another solution: move the parts further apart so you can move the vias off the pads.

Comment: The hole size is 12mil but even if I reduce it to 10mil, it doesn't help a lot. These pads belong to the decoupling capacitors on the bottom layer for a BGA chip, so they can't put further apart. Blinde vias are beyond my budget. Therefore, I have to try to find another  PCB shop which may be a bit more expensive.